# Copy value of one form into the hidden field of a second form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, copy

I have a page with multiple forms, however all forms need to take the value of a radio button in the products form.  Below is a simplified version of my forms which are all on the same page.

```
<form name="products" method="post" action="" />
<input id="prod_name" name="prod_name" type="radio" value="Product 1" checked />
<input id="prod_name" name="prod_name" type="radio" value="Product 2" />
</form>

<form name="delivery_method1" method="post" action="" />
<input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value=""/>
<input type="image" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form name="delivery_method2" method="post" action="" />
<input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" value=""/>
<input type="image" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I understand I should be able to copy the value of "prod_name" into the hidden field of "item_name" using JavaScript however I have tried a number of solutions but they haven't worked.

I have very little JavaScript knowledge so I would appreciate if someone could provide me with a full function and details of how the function is actioned from within the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID attributes should be **unique**. If you don't need them, remove these. If you're using `id=...` for styling purposes, replace all occurences of `id=` by `class=`, and replace the sharp (`#`) in the CSS by a dot.

When a form is submitted, only elements with a `name` attribute are sent.
This should work:

```
....
<script>
function fill(value) {
    var forms = document.forms;
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        if (forms[i].item_name) forms[i].item_name.value = value;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
<form name="products" method="post" action="">
<input onchange="fill(this.value)" name="prod_name" type="radio" value="Product 1" checked />
<input onchange="fill(this.value)" name="prod_name" type="radio" value="Product 2" />
</form>
...
```

All form elements are accessible through their name at the `form` element. All forms are accessible (by name or by their index in the document) through the `document.forms` object.

When the radio selection changes, function `fill()` is called, passing `this.value` as an argument. From the context of the radio input elements, `this.value` points to the value of the radio element.

Then, we loop through all forms in the document. If `item_name` is an element in the form, the value is updated.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this has got me a lot closer than I have been however it is passing the value 'undefined' - any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Instead of trying to retrieve the name through the function, I've passed it as an argument in the HTML source.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Rob, excellent answer, and one I can actually learn something from...have a great day.

Comment: There is a missing '/' for the close </script> delimiter.