# How to get a html spam value and copy to another html field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I already use $_POST to send data from this form to another page. However, there is one field that I need to copy its value to another field, as below(id="valparc" -> id of the field to copy):

This field varies depending on the user's choices.
What I need to do is take the value of this field and copy to another when the user clicks "submit".

Here is the html

```
   <section class="form-section">
        <div id="c-mask"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-6">
          <div class="form-lp">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="title-form">Quanto sua empresa precisa?</h1>
              </div>
              <form action="/calculadora/enviar.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <div class="value-range-total">
                    <span>R$</span>
                    <span id="slidernumber">3000</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="range" name="valor" min="1000" step="500" max="10000" value="3000" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                  <span class="value-range">R$ 1mil</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                  <span class="value-range text-right">R$ 10mil</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <h2 class="title-form">Em quantas parcelas?</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line">6x</button>-->
                     <label for="6x" id="l6x" class="lblcheck">6x</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="6x" name="parcelas" value="6x" placeholder="6x" class="ipt-check">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line">12x</button>-->
                     <label for="12x" id="l12x" class="lblcheck active">12x</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="12x" name="parcelas" checked value="12x" placeholder="6x" class="ipt-check">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line active">18x</button>-->
                     <label for="18x" id="l18x" class="lblcheck">18x</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="18x" name="parcelas" value="18x" placeholder="6x" class="ipt-check">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line">24x</button>-->
                     <label for="24x" id="l24x" class="lblcheck">24x</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="24x" name="parcelas" value="24x" placeholder="6x" class="ipt-check">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line">36x</button>-->
                     <label for="36x" id="l36x" class="lblcheck">36x</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="36x" name="parcelas" value="36x" placeholder="6x" class="ipt-check">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 p-5">
                    <!--<button class="button-line">48x</button>-->
                     <label for="48x" id="l48x" class="lblcheck">48x
                        <input type="radio" id="48x" name="parcelas" value="48x" class="ipt-check">
                     </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      <h3 class="second-title-form">Parcelas a partir de:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                      <h4 class="title-form total-form">R$<span name="presta" id="valparc">357,83</span><span class="ast">*</span></h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <button class="btn-blue-light" id="finalbtn">SOLICITAR COTAÇÃO</button>
                </div>
                  <div class="boxenviar">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required class="ipt_form">
                    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Telefone" id="tel" required class="ipt_form">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required class="ipt_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="whats" value="99999999999">
<input type="hidden" name="valparc" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="solicitar cotação" class="ipt_sbmt">
                  </div>
              </form>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <small class="info-form"><span class="ast">*</span> Esta é uma simulação. A análise real é individual e varia de empresa para empresa, para conhecer a sua, solicite uma cotação online.</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Doesn't need to be an "input" I just need this field on the form to stay hidden and get the value of the other one.

field to receive the data --

```
<input type="hidden" name="valparc" value="">
```

This field to be copied is dinamic and is generated by js below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("[type=range]").change(function(){
        var newval= $(this).val();
        $("#slidernumber").text(newval);
          
         if ($('#6x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 6)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 6) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
         } else if ($('#12x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 12)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 12) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#18x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 18)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 18) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
              
         } else if ($('#24x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 24)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 24) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#36x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 36)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 36) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         } else if ($('#48x').is(':checked')) {
             var result2 = newval * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 48)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 48) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
             
         }
      });
        $('#l6x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').addClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 6)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 6) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l12x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').addClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 12)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 12) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l18x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').addClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 18)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 18) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l24x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').addClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 24)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 24) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l36x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').addClass('active');
            $('#l48x').removeClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 36)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 36) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        });  
        $('#l48x').click(function(){
            var valnew = $("[type=range]").val();
            $('#l6x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l12x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l18x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l24x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l36x').removeClass('active');
            $('#l48x').addClass('active');
             var result2 = valnew * ((Math.pow((1+0.06), 48)*0.06)/(Math.pow((1+0.06), 48) - 1));
             $('#valparc').text(result2.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
        }); 
          $('#finalbtn').click(function(){
             $('.boxenviar').css('display','block'); 
             $('#c-mask').css('display','block'); 
          });
          $('#c-mask').click(function(){
             $('.boxenviar').css('display','none'); 
             $('#c-mask').css('display','none'); 
          });
          
    });
    </script>
```

This is my very first job with js and please, be patient. I dont know much (yet).

When the user chooses the loan in 12X or other the field "valparc" change its value. I have tried many thing that a saw here, but no sucess yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy value of one form into the hidden field of a second form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702819/copy-value-of-one-form-into-the-hidden-field-of-a-second-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to populate that field at the point of form.submit. You'd attach an event listener to the submit button, prevent it from automatically submitting, grab the text you want and apply it to the hidden elements value. Finally, you can submit the form once that's all done.

Note that your html didn't show the form opening tag, and you may have multiple forms on the page, so I referenced the enclosing form element with `.closest('form')`

```js
let b = document.querySelector('#finalbtn');
b.addEventListener('click', doValue)

function doValue(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stops automatic form submit
  let val = document.querySelector('span#valparc').innerText;
  document.querySelector('input[name="valparc"]').value = val;
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="valparc"]').value)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <h4 class="title-form total-form">R$<span id="valparc">357,83</span><span class="ast">*</span></h4>
    <!-- Field to copy -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <button class="btn-blue-light" id="finalbtn">SOLICITAR COTAÇÃO</button>
  </div>
  <div class="boxenviar">
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required class="ipt_form">
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Telefone" id="tel" required class="ipt_form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required class="ipt_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="valparc" value="" />
    <!-- This field will receive the copy data -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="solicitar cotação" class="ipt_sbmt">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I have update my post with more code. With you solution, fied "valparc" stop working. Could be me doing somethinh wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the other submit form button. Plus I made the snippet testable. Give that a go

Comment: you are a life saver. I have only one problem (maybe its my fault). A cant submit the last form (class="boxenviar"). The value is copyied, everything is right, just this little problem. I have uncommented the line you said. if you want to see it in action: https://wbarcelos.ml/calculadora

Comment: ok. I checked it out and edited my answer. you have this 2 part thing. The first part is about getting that value you want and opening this modal form. That is what my answer is for. The second part is about actually submitting the form, and that is separate and not part of my answer. I removed the lines of code that affect that... and hopefully it will work. Pls try it out.

Comment: I have no words to thank you. Besides helping me, I still actually learn something from your code. Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.